# Avoid Complex Number Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using sympy parsing to parse the string:

```
f = parse_expr('(x-1)^(1/3)')
```

When I use `f.subs({x:0})` it gives me Complex Number instead of -1.
How can I get rid of such behaviour?

I need something general, because function can be arbitrary and I don't know what variables will be there.

Thanks.

Comment: instead of -1? why would it give -1?  A complex number should be the right result there.

Comment: Because there are 3 numbers, that raised tot the 3rd power will give -1. They are -1 and 2 complex. I want -1 instead of complex.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code and finding out the function `real_root`, I managed to use transformations to write own converter.

Comment: I was thinking about this for a few days about how to fix it, but I didn't realize that there was `real_root`. SymPy is starting to reach a state of "any problem that you have is a problem that someone else has already had and solved".

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems like the best one. You may also be able to do the replacements symbolically, rather than trying to change the parser. Take a look at `atoms` and `xreplace`.

I just want to add that SymPy uses the convention that fractional powers are primitive roots with the smallest complex argument. Python itself follows these conventions:

```
>>> (-1+0j)**(1/3)
(0.5000000000000001+0.8660254037844386j)
```

There are many good reasons for doing this. The most obvious is that the second and third powers of the number will give you the other two roots:

```
>>> (-1+0j)**(2/3)
(-0.4999999999999998+0.8660254037844388j)
>>> (-1+0j)**(3/3)
(-1+0j)
```